# Does the default Ubuntu install have a file IO CRC/checksum already in place?

Tags: disk-management

I was wondering if linux/ubuntu or any os had a disk io crc that occurs naturally underneath the hood like it does for TCP/IP in the network transmissions world. Or is this just left to the user using md5sum and digest tools to check for file corruptions on their own? Was wondering if it is something that has been automated. Sorry if this is in the wrong stack exchange.

Comment: Probably wrong exchange, but the disk hardware typically does all sorts of hashchecking e.g. spinning disks might use a 10 bit byte, with the excess bits used for hash or sync etc.

Comment: @ubfan1 does a hash check mean like a high speed digest that would be better than a crc? should it be safe to assume that a m2/ssd disk might have the same measures?

Comment: I'd expect some error correction, 1 bit at least, better if 2. Depends upon how made.  crc is pretty simple, and not error correcting I think.  No idea  what ssds do, but error detection might be tied to the wear leveling.

Comment: CRC or *cylic redundancy checks* to ensure data integrity (CRC detects issues, just cannot correct them) is built into the file system (not OS itself). We don't support Linux itself, but Ubuntu allows and uses whatever protection is selected when the file-system itself is chosen. Recent Lubuntu QA includes ext4 (with & without encryption), xfs, & btrfs as tested *fs*, other flavors maybe more including main Ubuntu. However your question is more about *file-systems* themselves and not Ubuntu, and I suspect Ioff-topic (you didn't even mention an on-topic OS). https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

re: *"Or is this just left to the user using md5sum and digest tools to check for file corruptions on their own? Was wondering if it is something that has been automated."*

---

Check `man debsums`.

---

NAME

```
debsums - check the MD5 sums of installed Debian packages
```

SYNOPSIS

```
debsums [options] [package|deb] ...
```

DESCRIPTION

```
Verify  installed  Debian package files against MD5 checksum lists from
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums.
```

Answer (score 1):

Linux itself doesn't, but there may be some file system that supports Linux that does it. For example, ZFS, which is supported by Linux, I believe has some kind of checksum thing, but you'd have to read up about ZFS.